# Can I control the zoom percentage of different areas of my web page in response to Ctrl-+ and Ctrl--?

Tags: html, css, zooming, dreamweaver, ctrl

For reasons that I will describe if asked, I have some elements of my Dreamweaver web page in the `<body>` section of the HTML and others in the `<div class="twoColFixRtHdr">` Dreamweaver template that is nested within the  section. The two regions zoom at different rates when the user presses `Ctrl`-`+`, `Ctrl`-`-`, or `Ctrl`-`0`, so that they go badly out of alignment.

Is there a way to control the zoom rates so that I can keep the two regions in sync?

Comment: To clarify, there was HTML code that was deleted from my question. It should read "in the BODY section of the HTML and others in the DIV CLASS=TWOCOLFIXRTHDR template.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should have your html code escaped using backtick ` `<html>` ` that way it won't get "deleted" ;)

Answer (score 0):

percentage instead of pixels when you use percentage than by zooming your web will not be out of alignment

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kinds of changes the OP should make to fix his problem?